# Why are all options on the E-mini S&P 500 at the CME European style, except for quarterly option, which is American style?

Tags: united-states, options

The  [Chicago Mercantile Exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago_Mercantile_Exchange) (CME) has a variety of options on the E-mini S&P 500 (E1A,E2A,E3A,E4A,E5A,E1C,E2C,E3C,E4C,E5C,EW1,EW2,EW3,EW4,ES). All are European style, except for [the quarterly option (ES), which is American style](http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/equity-index/us-index/e-mini-sandp500_contractSpecs_options.html?optionExpiration=U7#optionProductId=138). What could explain this choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the reasons are historical. The quarterly American-style options used to be the only ones. The weekly and EOM European-style options were created later, probably to satisfy market demand:

> Weekly and end-of-month (EOM) options on futures provide European-style alternatives that complement our existing American-style options on standard and E-mini S&P 500 futures.
>
> *What are European-style options?*
>
> European-style options can be exercised only on the option’s expiration day. **This reduces some of the uncertainty for option sellers, as they cannot be assigned prior to expiration (American-style options can be exercised and assigned at any time up to expiration).**
>
> source: [CME - Weekly & End-of-Month (EOM) Options on Standard & E-mini S&P 500 Futures](http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/equity-index/weekly-eom-options-faq.html)  ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170731210901/http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/equity-index/weekly-eom-options-faq.html))

EDIT:

> [Historical First Trade Dates](http://www.cmegroup.com/media-room/historical-first-trade-dates.html#equityIndices)
>
> View a snapshot of product launch dates at CME Group, outlining the historical first trading date for futures and options contracts on our exchanges
>
> - E-mini options: 09/09/97
> - End-of-month Options on E-mini S&P 500: 05/21/06
> - Weekly Options on E-mini S&P 500: Weeks 1 & 2: 8/24/09, Week 4: 7/06/10